# How to inline combine arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, operators

Given two arrays, how to to pass a combination of both to a function, preferably with inline syntax?

```
var current = [1.01, 3.01, 2.42, 4.31];
var preview = [0.89, 3.15];

/*
 * pass both combined to a function, this is fictional syntax.
 * display(current + preview);
 */
```

What I mean by inline syntax to create an temporary array which gets passed. I don't want one of my arrays to be modified.

Comment: What is inline syntax?

Comment: @BoltClock I updated the question to explain that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create a new array containing the values from both:

```
display(current.concat(preview));
```